# Error of ordering day in R - undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I tried many ways to solve this problem, but I fail. Can anyone help me to figure out what's going wrong?

```
#I merge many data together in the begining
test <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by = c("Date")),
               list( VIX, EFFR, FFTR, OIL, SP500, TenY, ThreeM,
                     USDCAD, AAA, BAA))
#Name each column
colnames(test) <- c("Date","VIX","EFFR","FFTR","OIL","SP500","Ten_Year",
                    "Three_Month","USDCAD","AAA","BAA")

#Order these data by descending order
test <- test[order(test$Date, decreasing = TRUE)]
```

but an error happen all the time

> Error in `[.data.frame`(test, order(test$Date, decreasing = TRUE)) :
>     undefined columns selected

Can anyone tell me what mistake I did here?

Comment: You just need a comma in your test[] call at the end:`test <- test[order(test$Date, decreasing = TRUE),]`

Comment: Really appreciate! I didn't notice this one... Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to specify row, column format in your last line.

it should read

```
test <- test[order(test$Date, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

this way you're ordering the rows and keeping all the columns